# How do I calculate maximum frequency supported by an optocoupler say for example PC817 and what factors it depends on?

Tags: design, opto-isolator, phototransistor, circuit-design

I am currently working on isolating SPI bus.The SCLK for my non isolated version of design is 5MHz .How do I calculate whether the optocoupler is suitable for operation at this frequency of operation.Can somebody explain me design steps with PC817 say for 20KHz frequency so that in similar way I can design my circuit.

Comment: That sort of information is usually in the datasheet for the part.

Comment: You determine the Iforward current with respect to nominal value, frequncy characteristics and aging. Then you calculte the resitor, its all in datasheet.

Answer (score 5):

It's depend on the rise and fall time of the optocoupler, or rather I should say the propagation delay.
In the best case you'll get 143 kHZ (tr+tf)
[image]
 (see the [datasheet](http://i-makers.info/resource/pc817_ds.pdf)).
If your frequency is 5MHZ, the PC817 optocoupler isn't the best choice. The optocoupler propagation delay is more than the SPI clock period (1/frequency).
In [this](http://www.powersystemsdesign.com/optimize-data-rates-in-isolated-spi-buses) link you'll understand how to choose a suitable optocoupler to your SPI bus.

Comment: You forgot td and ts (which are not specified, yay); any difference will influence the pulse width distortion. The cut-off frequency is not really useful because a −3 dB sine wave signal isn't digital anymore.

Comment: The td and ts are about few nano seconds. For the cut-off frequency, i agree with you it for AC signals.